# How to debug "com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure"?

Tags: java, mysql, unix, jdbc

I'm doing a Java project where it needs to connect it to a database. but there's the problem is when I run my code it shows me the exception:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Here is my code:

```
public Connection cc;
public Statement stm;
public ResultSet rr;

public void Class() {

    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        cc = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://69.89.31.241:2083/table", "user", "pass");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Ok");
    } catch (Exception e) {
       System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

Now if I try this way in localhost it works but not on my live server. My server is **Server: Localhost via UNIX socket**.

Comment: Check your network connection to the 69.89.31.241 machine and verify that a mysql server is running on it. Also check firewall rules.

Comment: I've done ping onto this ip and it responds.

Comment: Try to connect to mysql server with a mysql client and you will know if the server is running.

Comment: MySQL Connector/J can only connect through a TCP/IP socket, it cannot connect through a Unix socket, see the linked duplicate, especially the part _"commenting out "skip-networking""_

Answer (score 0):

First things first:

- Check your network connection to the external IP where you've hosted your MySQL Database
- Try to connect to the MySQL Database using a client like SQL Yog
- Once these steps are done, you'll know if there are any issues in connecting to the MySQL database at all
- Even after these if you are not able to connect to your MySQL database, then you will have to make the following change on your `my.cnf` file

**my.cnf:**

```
bind-address = 69.89.31.241
```

And if you don't have any user login issues, you should be able to connect to the MySQL Database from your Java code.